# What Is The Proper Name For {!recordId} Type References?

Tags: administration, urlhacking, sidebar, menu

What is the **proper name for references** such as:

- {!recordId}

It's not a "**field**".  "id" would be the field.

When creating a custom button, this is referenced as a "**merge field**".

I'm attempting to use it when customizing the Force.com menu where apparently you can use these references (trying to confirmed) in URLs.  So far, the brackets are being percent-encoded and breaking the resultant URL...

Comment: It would be the **Object API Name** dot **Id** - for example Account.Id or MyCustomObject__c.Id - if I understand what you are asking correctly

Comment: It is just a value in a pick list. If you pick it the merge field that is placed in the custom button is as I stated in the previous comment **Account.Id**

Comment: No Idea. Suggest your goto an object, click new button, then from the field drop down (pick list) select "record id" - You will see that the merge field is as I stated. I really do not know what the context here is other than that sorry

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/164227/force-com-sidebar-reference-data-from-current-screen-on-urls

Comment: @Eric - testing your thought (at least I think it's what you meant) - I'm opening a new custom button on the object, and checking references to merge fields versus this reference....................   and..  I see that "recordId' is called by it's "real name" = rstk__sohdr__c.Id ........ if there was at least a period, I'd get it, but i don't.   The question on the Force.com sidebar is now answered by me, and now I'm opening one to discuss what variables/fields/whatever are available TO the Force.com menu BESIDES "recordId".   Thanks for the assist.   This question is still pertinent (name).

Comment: (I also tried substituting another "merge field" with a "record" prefix on Force.com ...... "Name".... did not work, so it's not "record" replacing the object name)

Comment: I have no idea what you are confused about. recordid = Account.Id and recordname = Account.Name (API Name.FieldName)

Comment: Nope.  That is absolutely not the case.  But thanks for trying.  It's rather annoying.  See:   http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/164357/what-references-to-fields-variables-are-available-to-the-force-com-menu

Comment: And it's not "recordid", it's "recordId" as well.  (sigh)

Comment: How can I (or would someone) mark this as "Closed" (unanswered)?    Since I apparently don't have the skill necessary to make it clear to a few people that this is a VERY DIFFERENT question (what is the reference CALLED), I just want to close it WITHOUT deleting it.

Comment: This question is already closed