# Force.Com Sidebar - Reference Data From Current Screen On URLs?

Tags: force.com, administration, urlhacking, sidebar, menu

I am being lead to believe this is possible:

A URL on the Force.Com Sidebar Menu which references data from the currently open page.  i.e., `/{!recordId}?nooverride=1`

[image]

However, this does not work.  The brackets simply turn into percent encoded references on the resultant page.

Is it possible to pass information onto a URL on the Force.Com sidebar?

Comment: What are you trying to do with that?

Comment: Use the Object Api Name dot Id. I believe whatever that is is meant to be a placeholder or an example. Did you even try the suggestion from your previous question and at the start of this comment? If so did it work or not

Comment: Where do you get a "add custom link" option on the sidebar?  Is that a chrome extension?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that the reference "recordid" needs to have "I" capitalized (**case sensitive**):

```
/{!recordId}?nooverride=1
```

So, yes, you CAN pass certain information to the Force.com sidebar menu.

---

I unfortunately have no clue where this recordId reference comes from or is documented.  I am opening another question about that as I've investigated, and find no help online, and the source of the page has references "like this" but the other variables found there do not work (see below).  At least "recordId" works for passing the current Id being viewed into the URL on the Force.com menu.

**UPDATE**:  Also tried "merge field" references from Custom Button editor, replcing objectname with "record" (believing maybe, like "objectname.Id" that this is the "format).  *This did not work for other "merge fields".*

**For reference, the page source being tested:**

[image]

**Link to NEW question:**   [What "References" To Fields/Variables Are Available To The Force.com Menu?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/164357/what-references-to-fields-variables-are-available-to-the-force-com-menu)