# What "References" To Fields/Variables Are Available To The Force.com Menu?

Tags: force.com, administration, urlhacking, customization, menu

In an effort to document this as research is yielding nothing so far, **I'd like to document what "fields"** (or "variables") **are available to the Force.com Sidebar Menu** for assembling useful URLs to other records or features.

**Related to**:   [Force.Com Sidebar - Reference Data From Current Screen On URLs?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/164227/force-com-sidebar-reference-data-from-current-screen-on-urls)

---

**SUCCESS:**   When adding "recordId" (case sensitive), you can use the current record's SF ID on the URL.

[image]

---

**INFO:**   In an attempt to reverse engineer what is available other than "recordId", I searched and also looked in the Source code of the page to see where "recordId" might be.  Found it (the only two instances are shown below).

[image: Source code of the page the URL is used on]

---

**FAIL:**   I tried one of the other variables from the same section of Source code; it did not work.   It leaves the (potential) field/variable name and also encodes the brackets into percent-values.

[image]

---

**FAIL:**   Since the syntax is similar to "merge fields" on a Custom Button, I tried references from there on the same object; also tried replacing "objectname" on the reference with "record" to mimic the "Id" reference.  Did not work.

[image]

---

**Also related to**:   [What Is The Proper Name For {!recordId} Type References?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/164214/what-is-the-proper-name-for-recordid-type-references)

This Question proves that you can pass SOME data to the Force.com Sidebar Menu (in this case, the "Id" of the record currently being viewed).

Comment: How do you get this menu with the custom links to show up in the tab? I was going to try and replicate but I do not see what you are seeing. There must be a setting or something right?

Comment: I've been taking that for granted (it's been there since day 1 for me).  Checking..................

Comment: Try altering "Customize Application" and also the checkbox shown....... https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000DGPtAAO  ....that may be it (though it does not specifically mention the "Add Custom Links" functionality - I search/find nothing about that?!

Comment: As well:  In my case, it is showing up as you see it on MANAGED PACKAGE VISUALFORCE PAGES that I cannot alter.    May behave differently there(?).

Comment: Yea, the Standard force.com quick access menu does not have what you are showing which is why I believe we are having trouble helping you. It looks like RootStock is doing some JS manipulation to create a quick access menu. The force.com quick access menu is not available in VF. I would reach out to RootStock to get their input

Comment: Why does that not surprise me?  Oh, right, Rootstock.     -Thanks.... checking with them.